# Multiple FileUploads with Multiple Submit Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have for example 5 fileupload controls and Also I have a submit button for each of them (in front of each fileupload control) which will upload that fileupload's selected file(s).

But There is a problem, when I click on (for example) second submit button to upload second fileupload's file(s), we will have a post back and other fileupload's file(s) will reset to empty. How can I manage such situation so when the user click on a submit button, the related fileupload's file(s) upload and the other fileupload's file(s) stay in their states. Hope I'm clear enough.

A Picture for better Result:

[image]

Comment: Are you using asp.net web forms or MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer - this is just modification of great answer here: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)
And I'm assuming you have jQuery.

```
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fu1" runat="server" CssClass="fu1" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="upload(this,'.fu1'); return false" Text="Submit" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fu2" runat="server" CssClass="fu2" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" OnClientClick="upload(this,'.fu2'); return false"  Text="Submit" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function upload(element,selector)
    {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', $(selector)[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Page.Form.Action %>',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            // Form data
            data: formData,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then within `Page_Load`:

```
Page.Form.Attributes["enctype"] = "multipart/form-data";
var file = Request.Files["image"];
if (file != null)
{
  // do something with the file
}
```

Comment: It does not work, Clicking buttons will have no effect.

Comment: It does work for me. Check out https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouuu8kuapk0fgam/Form.zip?dl=0